# Google Maps WebService API - show directions result on map

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, google-maps-api-3

EDIT:

1. How is it possible to get a    DirectionsResult    json object from Google maps Web Service APIv3 without breaking the "laws" of xss?
2. if so, how is it possible to parse that result and show it on a map (in the js API I use DirectionsRenderer) ?

I can do the above with the js API, but am failing miserably with the Web Service.  also, use of JQuery / JQM is available.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need the whole JavaScript interpreter/runtime just to parse JSON.  You can find JSON parsers written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't actually want to execute Javascript, you just want to parse JSON.  There are [many libraries](http://json.org/java/) available to do this.

Comment: but i actually want NOT to use the javascript api v3

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Javascript [OpenLayers Library](http://openlayers.org/) displaying map data including **Google Maps** in most modern web browsers, with no server-side dependencies and [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/openlayers-wrapper)'s OpenLayers Wrapper which contains server side wrapper component for OpenLayers Maps.

Check out some of the applications that were built using these tools:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Thakns Korhan, does this support Routing? Directions? UTF-8? location searches in other languages?

Comment: Your welcome, Pingi. OpenLayers support both routing and directions.  You can find plenty of useful source in the web for these characteristics of the library. Furthermore, you can set your program's character encoding in your application since you will be developing with Java.